# The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator

Tags: sql-server, jpa, time, eclipselink

I have an application using EclipseLink and SQL Server.

When I execute the below JPQL query on a column of SQL Server type `Time`:

```
VisitMasterTable.bookingTime between '08:00:00' and '08:59:00'
```

then I get below error:

> The data types `time` and `datetime` are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: first off -what's the column definition for bookingTime? Next: Why don't use use PreparedStatement instead of literals?

Comment: the column definition `bookingTime time,` i'm using JPA

Comment: Can you include your query here?

Comment: JPQL Query
`select  
 VisitMasterTable from  VisitMasterTable as VisitMasterTable 
where 
  VisitMasterTable.bookingDate = '2016-08-15'
 and VisitMasterTable.bookingTime between  '08:00:00' and '08:59:00'`

Comment: Generated SQL 
` SELECT ............
 FROM 
 VISITMASTERTABLE t0 
  WHERE ((t0.BOOKINGDATE = {d '2016-08-15'}) AND (t0.BOOKINGTIME BETWEEN {t '08:00:00'} AND {t '08:59:00'}))`

Comment: Can you try with adding 'sendTimeAsDateTime=false' to your connection url string?

Comment: in sql server managment studio ian replaces `{t '08:00:00'}` with  `'08:00:00'` the query run correctly

Comment: where to write`sendTimeAsDateTime=false'

Comment: Your hibernate connection url string like: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db_name>/blabla...'

Comment: At the end, add it like '?sendTimeAsDateTime=false' or if you have any other query parameter '&sendTimeAsDateTime=false'

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ChildClinicDb?sendTimeAsDateTime=false

Comment: return error `Cannot open database "ChildClinicDb?sendTimeAsDateTime=false" requested by the login. The login failed`

Comment: i'm using eclipse link

Comment: Could you please try again with 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ChildClinicDb;sendTimeAsDateTime=fa‌​lse'

Comment: Thank you very much it's run

Comment: Could you please accept my answer below?

Comment: i can't show accept button how can i do that

Comment: Below, I wrote now, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `sendTimeAsDateTime=f‌​a‌​lse` to your connection string like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=<db_name>;sendTimeAsDateTime=f‌​a‌​lse
```